# else if() Почему именно так?

Tags: java

Чем конструкция

```
if (names.length == 0) {
    // Some code
}

if (names.length == 1) {
    // Some code
}
```

Отличается от

```
if (names.length == 0) {
    // Some code
}

else if (names.length == 1) {
    // Some code
}
```

Иными словами, вопрос :

Обязательно ли писать else ?

За первый вариант дадут по шапке в рабочем коде ?

**UPD : Убрал return**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В принципе достаточно почитать, что делает else и ответ станет ясен.

В первом случае второй if будет анализироваться независимо от результата первого.

Во втором же только если первый if даст отрицательный результат.

Comment: т.е я правильно понимаю, что второй вариант более производительный (В каком-то смысле) ?

Comment: Да. И более понятен для чтения, потому что сразу видно, что это один блок.

Comment: @PerfectVoyage Если, например, в первом блоке длина names увеличится на единицу в случае с if оно пройдет второй блок, а в случае с else if оно даже проверять условие не будет - сразу мимо пройдет, хотя удовлетворяет условию